# How to compare two psv files through Robot framework; is it possible?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, delimiter, robotframework

I have two psv (pipe-separated) files, I need to compare the data columnwise.

How can I compare those two files, is it possible to compare two psv files through Robot??

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "psv file"? That could mean a pipe-separated value file, a plaustation save file, or perhaps something else.

Comment: its pipe-separated value file

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built-in to the robot framework specifically for psv files. However, assuming they are text files, you can write a keyword in python that compares the two files. Python has a [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) which makes it easy to parse such files, assuming your data is well-formed.

For example, create a file named `PsvLibrary.py` with the following contents. Be aware: this isn't production-quality code. It assumes the data is well formed and that each file has exactly the same number of rows, and the number of rows isn't gargantuan. The point is to show the general idea, not to give a fully functioning library:

```
import csv

class PsvLibrary(object):
    def compare_columns(self, column_number, filea, fileb):
        with open(filea, "rb") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
            filea_data = [line for line in reader]

        with open(fileb, "rb") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
            fileb_data = [line for line in reader]

        # for the given column, make sure the data in file a
        # matches the data in file b
        c = int(column_number)
        for n, (row_a, row_b) in enumerate(zip(filea_data, fileb_data)):
            if row_a[c] != row_b[c]:
                raise Exception("line %d: '%s' != '%s'" % (n+1, row_a[c], row_b[c]))
```

You can then use this library in a test case like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | PsvLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of comparing columns in pipe-separated files
| | compare columns | 1 | file1.psv | file2.psv
```

For testing, create a file named `file1.psv` with the following data:

```
apple|red
orange|orange
grape|green
```

Create a second file named `file2.psv` with the following data. Note that the last line is different in the second column:

```
apple|red
orange|orange
grape|purple
```

If you run the above test you should see this as the output:

```
==============================================================================
Example                                                                       
==============================================================================
Example of reading a pipe-separated file                              | FAIL |
line 3: 'green' != 'purple'
```

Comment: I would recommend using the csv module in Python. You can use a custom separator such as a pipe.

Comment: If I need to compare two csv files , what changes should be done to the above python script ?

I have tried replacing '|' with ',' in delimiter section ,but seems like it wont work  . It throughs error saying "Line contains Null byte"